# Android java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android error for .so libraries

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

so libraries to my project for ffmpeg camera but I have got some errors when I load the library.

I'm getting error like that "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android" .

My .so files directory is src-main-jniLibs-armeabi - so files. When I loading the so file gettting error I can't load the so file. I have tried many answer but still going this error.

If you want other config files I can load here.

Error log is here also

```
09-14 17:40:33.739 19728-20196/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #6
                                               Process: com.leadtimeapp.io.internal.debug, PID: 19728
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.leadtimeapp.io.internal.debug-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.leadtimeapp.io.internal.debug-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.leadtimeapp.io.internal.debug-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libjniavformat.so"
                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586)
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avformat.<clinit>(avformat.java:40)
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avformat.av_register_all(Native Method)
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.NewFFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(NewFFmpegFrameRecorder.java:302)
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.FFmpegRecorderActivity.initVideoRecorder(FFmpegRecorderActivity.java:464)
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.FFmpegRecorderActivity.access$1400(FFmpegRecorderActivity.java:66)
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.FFmpegRecorderActivity$2.doInBackground(FFmpegRecorderActivity.java:368)
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.FFmpegRecorderActivity$2.doInBackground(FFmpegRecorderActivity.java:360)
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.leadtimeapp.io.internal.debug-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.leadtimeapp.io.internal.debug-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.leadtimeapp.io.internal.debug-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libavformat.so"
                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:577)
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540) 
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avformat.<clinit>(avformat.java:40) 
                                                   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avformat.av_register_all(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.NewFFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(NewFFmpegFrameRecorder.java:302) 
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.FFmpegRecorderActivity.initVideoRecorder(FFmpegRecorderActivity.java:464) 
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.FFmpegRecorderActivity.access$1400(FFmpegRecorderActivity.java:66) 
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.FFmpegRecorderActivity$2.doInBackground(FFmpegRecorderActivity.java:368) 
                                                   at com.leadtimeapp.io.ffmpeg.FFmpegRecorderActivity$2.doInBackground(FFmpegRecorderActivity.java:360) 
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
09-14 17:40:34.168 19728-19790/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f643ae900 
cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f76e3e1a0 arg=0x0
09-14 17:40:34.168 19728-19790/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f643ae900 
cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

My gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

def buildVersionCode = new Date().format("yyMMddHHmm", 
TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul")).toInteger()
def buildVersionName = "1.1.2"
def SupportVersion = '25.3.1'
def OkHttpVersion = '3.2.0'
def RetrofitVersion = '2.0.2'
def FacebookVersion = '4.+'
def GSonVersion = '2.6.2'

android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

playAccountConfigs {
    defaultAccountConfig {
        ...
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "...."
    resValue "string", "app_name", "..."
    resValue "string", "face_app_id", "...."
    minSdkVersion 16
    playAccountConfig = playAccountConfigs.defaultAccountConfig
    //noinspection OldTargetApi
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode buildVersionCode
    versionName buildVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true


}

signingConfigs {
    ....
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false        // true by default
    checkAllWarnings false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    ignoreWarnings true       // false by default
    quiet true                // false by default
}

sourceSets {
    main.jni.srcDirs = []
    main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                        output.outputFile.name.replace("-release", "-release-" + buildVersionName + "-" + buildVersionCode)
                )
            }
        }
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }

    productFlavors {
        arm7 {
            // in the future, ndk.abiFilter might also work
            ndk {
                abiFilter 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }
        arm8 {
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilter 'armeabi'
            }
        }
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter 'x86'
            }
        }
        x86_64 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter 'x86_64'
            }
        }
        mips {
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'mips', 'mips64'
            }
        }
        universal {
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'mips', 'mips64', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            }
        }
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    checkAllWarnings true
    htmlReport true
    htmlOutput file("lint-report.html")
    checkReleaseBuilds true

    disable 'MissingTranslation'
    disable 'UnusedResources'
    disable 'IconLauncherShape'
    disable 'GoogleAppIndexingApiWarning'
    disable 'SelectableText'
    error 'CommitTransaction'
    error 'InconsistentArrays'
    error 'Registered'
    error 'ManifestOrder'
}

}

play {
track = 'alpha'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['.jar', '.so'])
compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
compile files('libs/javacv.jar')

compile project(':camera')
compile project(':VideoRecorder')

compile("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SupportVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
compile("com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SupportVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
compile("com.android.support:design:$SupportVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-ui'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
compile("com.android.support:support-v4:$SupportVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
}
compile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-vector-drawable'
}

compile(group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets'
}
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '3.2.1-1.3'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '3.2.1-1.3', classifier: 'android-arm'

compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$GSonVersion"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OkHttpVersion"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RetrofitVersion"
compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:$FacebookVersion"


compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
compile 'com.github.zhaokaiqiang.klog:library:1.4.0'
compile 'com.github.filippudak.progresspieview:library:1.0.4'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.7'
compile 'io.paperdb:paperdb:1.5'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0'
compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0'
compile 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.8@aar'
compile 'com.github.ihsanbal:scissors:1.1.3'
compile 'org.zakariya.stickyheaders:stickyheaders:0.7.5'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.8'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'com.github.wooplr:Spotlight:1.2.3'
compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
compile 'com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

}
```

Comment: Don't post approximately what your error messages are. Post the _full, exact_ error messages. And you should also post any java and/or c++ code that the error message(s) refer to.

Comment: @Michael I have added error logs

Comment: Please add the make file, and the piece of code loading the jni library.